# Deleting a number from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to remove a number from an array, for example this array:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

I want to remove the number 2 so i will get this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 3 )
```

but I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => [2] => 3 )
```

What I did is to check if the number 2 is in the array and removing it with unset. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: after i json_encode the array i get this thing: 
    {"0":"","1":"1","2":"2","4":"4"}
istead of 
["","2","3", "4"]

Comment: Unclear question, show your code to us. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the numeric indices of your array after you removed the element with `array_values`.

```
unset($myArray[1]);
$myArray = array_values($myArray);
```

Comment: Judging from the question, he removes an element by value, not by key.

Comment: @Nordenheim: Yes, but he can solve his index problem with array_values nevertheles.

Comment: array_values fixed it, the problem was when I encode to json the array with those indexes its messing up. Thx :)